# button disable not work inside form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Greeting developers, currently i learn javascript. i try do two button one is for add and another one is for unfriend which is disable. once click add it show prompt box to enter subject.after enter subject the unfriend box should able to click and add button disable.my problem is now my all function doesn't work. the buttons are still same. i think that is because of form.developers please help me to know what is my fault in coding.

```js
function disableButton(btn) {
  var subject = prompt("Please enter Subject that want to study");
  if (subject != null) {
    form['subject'].value = subject;
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("add").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("btn").value = "request sent";
  }
}

function disableButton(add) {
  document.getElementById("add").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("btn").value = "Add friend";
  form.submit();
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" onSubmit="disableButton(btn);return false;">
    <input type="hidden" id="subject" name="subject" />
    <input type="submit" value="unfriend" id="add" onClick="ableButton(add)" disabled/>
    <input type="submit" value="add" id="btn" id="btn" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You cannot give multiple functions the same name....